# Room Database check if number is already used

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

after four days of searching and trying I've got no other idea than asking you on stackoverflow. In my android app written in Kotlin, I have a room database where I pass some Informations of an battery, each battery has of course an unique id that is autogenerated and a number witch can be choosen by the user of the app but I don't want that any number can be reused, so it should be unique for each battery. Now I'm trying to find a way to check if the database already contains this number. But how do I do that?

[image: Screenshot of my Database]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can write a method in "dao" to return count of batteries available with given number like below.

```
@Query("SELECT count(*) FROM battery_table WHERE Number = :number")
int getBatteriesAvailableWithGivenNumber(int number);
```

If size is 0,then number is unique and it can be used for your purpose.

Comment: Ok, I've tried it, and I see it in the Log that it is working, but I have a problem getting the data to the activity because in my viewmodel I use kotlincorutines and I cant get it to work so the function is returning an Int, and when I dont use the viewmodel the app crashes becuase I run it on mainthread

Comment: Still don't get it how to run it on an backroundthread and recieve the Int

Comment: Hi @LuX1nAt0r I had not used Kotlin.But in our case we create wrapper around database which is responsible for database operations and also to store data in Ram.When we are doing operations like above,what we do is instead of fetching from DB we fetch from ram.So,response will be quick.